# How to get ReferenceTime without time

Tags: momentjs

MomentJS has option "referanceTime" - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/ and it displays datetime like this `Last Monday 2:30 AM`
Problem is when I have date without time - it displays `Last Monday 0:00 AM` - how get rid of time when date hasn't got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 2.10.5 we can define our own render engine by invocation (second parameter of `calendar` function) - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/

But now we can use only strings not function to define pattern

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29262910/728393) but slightly more advanced.

I believe the only way to customize calendar time is by using a [custom locale](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/). In your case, you need to use a custom function.

Here's a somewhat complex, but complete way to do it:

```js
// Factory-type function that returns a function.
// Used to set argument (fstr) without using `bind` (since bind changes `this`)
var stripZeroTime = function (fstr) {
    return function () {
        if (this.format("H:mm:ss") === "0:00:00") { // if midnight
            return fstr.replace("LT", "") //remove time
                       .replace("at", "") //remove at
                       .replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim(); //strip extra spaces
        }
        return fstr;
    }
}
moment.locale('en-cust', {
    calendar: {
        lastDay: stripZeroTime('[Yesterday at] LT'), // Default format strings
        sameDay: stripZeroTime('[Today at] LT'),
        nextDay: stripZeroTime('[Tomorrow at] LT'),
        lastWeek: stripZeroTime('[last] dddd [at] LT'),
        nextWeek: stripZeroTime('dddd [at] LT'),
        sameElse: stripZeroTime('L')
    }
});
```

[Demo with test cases](http://fiddle.jshell.net/slicedtoad/ddf3d5zy/1/)

A simpler way would be to just strip off the `0:00:00` when it's midnight.

```js
function stripMidnight(m){
    if(m.format("H:mm:ss") === "0:00:00"){
        return m.calendar().replace("0:00:00","");
    }else{
        return m.calendar();
    }
}
```