# How to display just 'Today' with nothing else?

Tags: momentjs

I just want 'Today' if the datetime is within today.

```
moment().calendar()  // 'Today at 5:08PM'
```

Comment: var toDay = ((moment().calendar()).split(" "))[0]

Comment: Why dont you use string concatenation ?

Comment: @persianDeveloper  I understand `.split` by @Rajashekhar,  but concatenation, how?  I want to make use of the locale definitions in moment.
And @persianDeveloper, what if in some locales the result is `5:08PM xyz Today_In_That_Lang`?

Comment: The word 'Today' may be in `moment.localeData()` but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [custom locale](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/).

```js
moment.locale('en-cust', {
    calendar: { /*replace calendar format strings*/
        lastDay: '[Yesterday at] LT',
        sameDay: '[Today]', // <---
        nextDay: '[Tomorrow at] LT',
        lastWeek: '[last] dddd [at] LT',
        nextWeek: 'dddd [at] LT',
        sameElse: 'L'
    }
});
```

After running that, `moment().calendar();` will return `"Today"`.

All non-calendar behaviour will maintain the default `locale: 'en'` behaviour.

Note that you need to replace the whole calendar object and not just the `sameDay` property.

### Solution without hardcoding

I like this solution a lot but it does rely on a non-public momentjs api, `localeData._calendar` since there isn't a getter for this data. It also uses jquery for `extend`, let me know if you aren't using jquery.

```js
function correctToday(locale,strf){
    // copy and extend the locale's calendar data
    var localeCal = $.extend({}, moment.localeData(locale)._calendar, {'sameDay':strf});
    // Replace the locale's calendar data with the modified one (uses public setter)
    moment.locale(locale,{calendar:localeCal});
}

// Usage
correctToday('en',"[today]");
correctToday('fr',"[aujourd'hui]");
```

And some test cases:

```js
moment.locale();
moment().calendar(); //test changes
moment().subtract(22,'hours').calendar(); //test other cal functionality
moment().format(); //test non-cal functionality
moment().fromNow();

// Produces
// ["en", "today", "Yesterday at 12:09 PM", "2015-03-26T10:09:05-04:00", "a few seconds ago"]
// ["fr", "aujourd'hui", "Hier à 12:09", "2015-03-26T10:09:05-04:00", "il y a quelques secondes"]
```

### Toggle

You can use functions in place of strings for locale settings. So, the `correctToday` function above remains the same but if we want a toggle, we call it like:

```js
moment.timeOff = true; // this is the toggle, declare it somewhere globally accessible (I'm adding it to moment)
correctToday('en',function(){
    return moment.timeOff ? "[today]" : "[today at] LT";
});
```

If you don't like `"[today at] LT"` being hardcoded, store the original localeData._calendar before changing it and take the string from `.sameDay`.

Comment: Sorry my goal is to display only 'Today' in multiple locales. I would like to reuse the definitions already in moment source code.  If my system supports 3 locales, your idea means to make 3 custom locales?

Comment: It works.   A further question, if on the same page somewhere I need only 'Today', somewhere else I need the standard 'Today at 5:08PM', is there any way to save the original setting and switch between the two?

Comment: Toggle works well.  Let me accept this answer, while I am still trying your [If you don't like .. hardcoded, store ..].    @slicedtoad